# Four WinAPI test questions

Tags: winapi, message

Following is an extraction of a WinAPI test quiz.
I've researched quite a bit, but haven't found the answers to these:

```
    1. Which statement, regarding dynamic link libraries (DLL), is WRONG:
    a) DLLs can be used to exchange data between applications in Windows
    b) DLLs can call Windows modules
    c) DLLs can use DOS file functions
    d) DLLs can control a user dialog in Windows

    2. Which statement, regarding the messages in Windows, is WRONG:
    a) messages can be exchanged between the objects of an application
    b) messages can be generated when events happen
    c) messages can be exchanged between applications
    d) messages can be exchanged with the help of temporary queue storage

    3. Which statement, regarding the system message queue, is CORRECT:
    a) it serves for communication and exchange of messages between applications
    b) it serves for exchange of messages between common resources
    c) it serves for temporary storage of messages from the peripheral devices
    d) it serves for communication and exchange of messages between window objects

    4. In order to hide a window or a control, the following function is used:
    a) SetWindowHide
    b) HideWindow
    c) UnshowWindow
    d) DeleteWindow
```

I am absolutely positive question 4 is just wrong.
The correct answer is ShowWindow.

And I'm almost certain that 2 does not have a correct answer at all.

I have no additional details or clarifications about the questions.

Comment: Was this quiz administered in a school? Or did you find it online somewhere? Are you sure these are the questions verbatim? Because it's a rather badly written quiz as-is. Especially since none of the functions listed in question 4 exist in the Windows API.

Comment: The all 4 questions seem totally broken to me.

Comment: Yes, I am sure these are the questions - word for word.
Very badly written, I absolutely agree.
And hate to admit it's from a local University.

I've not had a problem with WinAPI and yet I feel unable to answer these. I agree with both of the above comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- 1c. DLLs are mainly used to share common code but objects stored in them are only available locally within the memory space within which that instance of a DLL is currently mapped.
- 2a. The answer to this one depends on your interpretation of the question. Strictly speaking you can. To send messages all you need is for the receiving end to have a window with a message loop to send to. For example WM_COPYDATA is 'sort of' used to exchange data between objects. If you view the receiving window as an 'object' and the sender (which does not need to be a window) to also be an 'object' then this does not hold.
- 3d. Again as above it depends on your interpretation of 'object'. A message can be sent **from** an application that does not have a window.
- 4.. None. You would either use SetWindowPos() or more commonly
  ShowWindow() with SW_HIDE

Comment: 1 - how does this prevent them from using DOS file functions (as the answer pointed should declare a WRONG statement, like the question expects)
2 - but when you deny processing of a message that you cought in one object (window or otherwise) and "let it go", you can process it in another, which is kind of an exchange
3 - sadly, I don't have any more clarification, as I stated, but I agree with this one
4 - yes, that's just wrong.

Comment: 1 - MS-DOS API are accessed by invoking int 21 and in win32 you do not have this privilege from usermode. 2, 3 - I think these are really open to your interpretation of the question.

Comment: Thanks, Mike.
I agree with what you just said about 2 and 3.

Case closed.

Comment: Actually, the answer to #3 is C.  The _system_ message queue holds events from things like the keyboard and the mouse before they're routed to the appropriate thread message queue.

Comment: There are windows messages that are not generated by hardware peripheral interaction. On top of that, the ones that do originate from a keyboard/mouse can be emulated.

Comment: @Mike: Perhaps Adrian McCarty wanted to stress on the word "system" before queue. There's perhaps a difference between "Windows messages" and "the Windows system queue", which I also wasn't aware of.
In that case, he could be right.